# El Capitan Finder is not automatically scrolling anymore

Tags: finder

I have the following problem since El Capitan:
My Finder is in column-view and I have a large number of files listed. So many that I have to scroll up and down. If I open a new file, it appears in alphabetical order at the position of N (new file). When I rename the file, it moves out of the Finder-window and I have to scroll up or down in order to fill the file.
In Yosemite Finder automatically scrolled with my renamed folder to its new position and I could fill it right away.
Can I reactivate this feature in El Capitan?
I hope you can follow my description of my problem ;)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You'll find that the empty column to the right is in fact the correct place. Up arrow then down arrow will refocus, but you don't actually have to in order to add contents to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!!! Just one final question: Is this a normal behavior of Finder or is this a problem only I have?

Comment: I think it's a bug, but it's one they never fixed.